# SonarQube : cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.file_sources' with unique index 'file_sources_file_uuid_uniq'. The duplicate key value is

Tags: data-migration, sonarqube-5.4

during the process migration of Sonar (from 4.5.7 to 5.4), we faced to an issue. The migration failed with this message :

```
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.file_sources' with uni
que index 'file_sources_file_uuid_uniq'. The duplicate key value is...
```

My database is an MS SQL Server. She's configured in FRENCH_CI_AS. I tried to change it in FRENCH_CS_AS, but it didn't solve the problem.

I've observed that, each time we restart the migration, the number of processed files was different. BUT it always failed by processing for the same file.
Any idea ?

Comment: can you check file_sources_file_uuid_uniq index and respective columns...

Comment: What do you mean by "check" ? What king of check do you want to test ?

Comment: it seems, there must be some duplicate data trying to get in table where you have above mentioned unique key constraint. As per unique constraint rule, table will not accept any duplicate record based on defined columns in a definition part. If possible share the definition part here so we can help you